# REST API issue in Android app

Tags: java, android

This is my REST API and I can't set any data to a MSSQL server. I have the following error:

```
Unable to resolve host "bmsoft.somee.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Here is my **RestAPI** class:

```
public class RestAPI {

    private final String urlString = "http://bmsoft.somee.com/Handler1.ashx";

    private static String convertStreamToUTF8String(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        String result = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            int readedChars = 0;
            while (readedChars != -1) {
                readedChars = reader.read(buffer);
                if (readedChars > 0)
                   sb.append(buffer, 0, readedChars);
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    private String load(String contents) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        w.write(contents);
        w.flush();
        InputStream istream = conn.getInputStream();
        String result = convertStreamToUTF8String(istream);
        return result;
    }


    private Object mapObject(Object o) {
        Object finalValue = null;
        if (o.getClass() == String.class) {
            finalValue = o;
        } else if (Number.class.isInstance(o)) {
            finalValue = String.valueOf(o);
        } else if (Date.class.isInstance(o)) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Locale("en", "USA"));
            finalValue = sdf.format((Date)o);
        } else if (Collection.class.isInstance(o)) {
            Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) o;
            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
            for (Object item : col) {
                jarray.put(mapObject(item));
            }
            finalValue = jarray;
        } else {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Method[] methods = o.getClass().getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.getDeclaringClass() == o.getClass()
                    && method.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC
                    && method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                    String key = method.getName().substring(3);
                    try {
                        Object obj = method.invoke(o, null);
                        Object value = mapObject(obj);
                        map.put(key, value);
                        finalValue = new JSONObject(map);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return finalValue;
    }

    public JSONObject SetTA(double tj,double aj,String code) throws Exception {
        JSONObject result = null;
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
        o.put("interface","RestAPI");
        o.put("method", "SetTA");
        p.put("tj",mapObject(tj));
        p.put("aj",mapObject(aj));
        p.put("code",mapObject(code));
        o.put("parameters", p);
        String s = o.toString();
        String r = load(s);
        result = new JSONObject(r);
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're receiving?

Comment: You have "any" error? Do you mean you _are_ getting an error or not? What does your logcat say?

Comment: And are you running `load()` on a background thread?

Comment: `I have any error` means that **you have error**. `I don't have any error` means that **you don't have error**. So do you have error, or you don't have it?

Comment: Unable to resolve host "bmsoft.somee.com": No address associated with hostname

Comment: do you have Internet permission in manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: then do you have internet connection? the error says it failed to resolve host.

Comment: yes Vlad I Have  internet connection

Comment: And can you access bmsoft.somee.com via the web browser on your phone?

Comment: This error occurs only in the android studio 2.2.3 But in android studio 2.1.0 works well